# IBM Cognos Analytics - Multiple rows into single row

Tags: repeater, cognos

I am using Cognos Analytics 11.0.4 and I am trying to concatenate multiple rows into a single row.

ID      Department

123456      Front Office

123456      Reception

123456      IT

What I would like to do:

ID      Department

123456      Front Office|Reception|IT

I tried creating a repeater with a new query, adding ID, Department to it, then setting up a master detail relationship between query1 ID and query2 ID, finally adding a text item with the | character.

When running the report I only get the below.

ID

123456

Anyone know what might be going wrong? It is like the repeater and | in query2 are ignored for the final output.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, as simple as it was, it took me a while to realise.
Exporting my report with the 'Run Excel Data' option couldn't handle the row operations required by the Repeater object.

Switching to 'Run Excel' resolved the issue.

Comment: As you discovered, your solution is sound, but your choice of output formats was questionable.  Run Excel Data and Run CSV return the results of the first query (not page, list, etc.) that Cognos finds.  Your repeater generated a second query.  Read the documentation.  IMO  Run Excel Data and Run CSV should not be available to most users.  Its only purpose appears to be to confuse users.  (Unless you think Cognos Analytics is an ETL tool.)